# on click fires twice only inside tabs()

Tags: php, jquery, html, onclick

I have a container on my page called `task1` containing a slideshow, back button and next button. The final page will have `task1` as one of a series of tabs(container called tasks). My `onClick` event works perfectly when I leave out the `tabs()` function. As soon as I add the tabs(), the `onClick` fires twice. I have checked other questions, but the most popular answer of "check if the code is written twice" does not hold any water.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<div class="content" id="tasks">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#task1">Review for Quiz</a></li>
    <li><a href="#task2">task 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#task3">task 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#task4">task 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#task5">Blackjack</a></li>
  </ul>                 

  <div class="content" id="task1"></div>
  <div class="content" id="task2"></div>
  <div class="content" id="task3"></div>
  <div class="content" id="task4"></div>
  <div class="content" id="task5"></div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$("#tasks").tabs();

$(".content").on('click','.yNext',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "task1php.php",
        async: true,
        type: "POST",
        data: {func: 3}
    }).success(function(data){
        alert(data);
        $("#task1").html(data);
    });
});
```

php to generate slides(.yNext is the next button and .yBack is back button):

```
if($slide == '55')
$slide = '1';
else
    $slide++;   
echo "<div class='yLeftSs'>";
echo "<input class='yBack' type='image' src='images/BackArrow.png' />";//back button
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='yCenterSs'>";
echo "<img class='ySlides' src='images/Task1_slides/Slide".$slide.".PNG'/>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='yRightSs'>";
echo "<input class='yNext' type='image' src='images/NextArrow.png' />";//next button
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: That is the next button. I have clarified this in the code. Thanks for pointing at the ambiguity.

Comment: Why are you using `<input>` for the buttons, instead of just `<img>`? These types of inputs are intended to be submit buttons for a form.

Comment: Are u always filling #task1 or other too? May be you bind click event twice with .yNext.

Comment: @Barmar, that is irrelevant to the problem. Also, you dont get the feeling of a button.

Comment: Just as a guess, try putting `return false` at the end of the click handler.

Comment: Returning false prevents the default action of the button. I'm not sure why it's necessary in this case, I suspect there's more to your code that you're not showing us that would explain it.

Comment: It goes back to Barmar's question about why you're using inputs (which you quickly dismissed as irrelevant.) These inputs have an expected behavior in all browsers (as he said they're expected as submissions for forms) and when you click it, it's trying to perform the expected function (which is a click) and then applying your click function on top of that. By adding his suggestion, you're negating one of the clicks.

Comment: The default action of a button is to submit the form that it's a part of. I'm not sure how that relates to what you're doing, or why it only happens when you use tabs. Maybe it has something to do with the way jQuery wraps the tab content.

Comment: Returning false also prevents the event from bubbling, perhaps that's the issue.

Comment: Ok, I jumped to dismiss. that being the case, is there a route to give a button effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `return false;` to the end of the click handler to prevent the default action and event bubbling. One of these seems to be triggering the handler again.